# Searching for pages in Google+ using Google API Search

Tags: php, google-api, google-plus

I'm trying to implement a solution that searches for pages in Google Plus, by name. What I see so far is that `google search api` offers the possibility to make a general search (web pages) and you cannot make a custom search, only in G+ pages in this case. Or am I missing something? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [people.search](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/search) API method to search for Pages and Profiles on Google+.

Comment: So, this means that `"objectType": "person"` can also be `"objectType": "page",` right? What I found so far in that API call is only `person`.

Comment: If you do a search for "google" there will be a bunch of pages as results.